# Why payment method does not come in default-Magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, payment, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I need some clarification before proceeding payments methods. Already vendor folder have payment, paypal, offline payment module, it also in enable mode while checking app/etc/config.php. But while checkout page no payment option will come like netbanking, cash on delivery.

my question is Magento 2 have any default payment gateway integration or need to look any extension?

if need to look extension, what is the best and free extension available in the market for magento 2? .

I am searching in magento connect but all are magento 1.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes my think is right, magento 2 have default payment methods. Its get display in checkout page when enable from backend side.

> Steps to enable **cash on delivery** payment methods:
>
> login to admin, then follow
>
> Store->Configuration->Sales->Payment Method->Cash on Delivery Payment ->Enabled->**YES**
>
> clear cache, and then go and check checkout page. Now you got cash on delivery payment method.

similarly more methods available there, choose as per your requirements. In my case I need Cash on Delivery only.

2. could search the Magento 2 extension in  [market place](https://marketplace.magento.com/) [thanks @Smartie, got this link from you]

Answer (score 1):

Magento Connect is not the place for 2.x extensions. You need [Magento Marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/) (just launched).

You will need a custom extension for what you require. For example, SagePay is not out the box in 2.x nor are many others. I am aware of some extensions that have been released for 2.x that are ports from 1.x so it would be worth looking to see if those can do the job.

Bare in mind, 2.x is in it's infancy. It will be some time before module developers can get the same level of coverage on 2.x

Comment: could you explain more about sagePay?(source link)